# Inject this field value directly into filter chain, the only method that uses it

Tags: java, spring-security, java-8, jwt, sonarqube

I am making code changes to not use deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Hence created a below class. When i run the application it seems to work fine. I had to verify two things here.

1. Does anyone think any more changes are needed here?
2. The other concern is when i make below changes, it gives me other sonar issue for two fields -
   jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint
   and jwtRequestFilter. The issue states " Inject this field value directly into filter chain, the only method that uses it". How can i fix this?

   ```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${SSL.ENABLE}")
    private boolean sslEnable;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/updatePassword").permitAll()
               .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()                        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);


        if (sslEnable) {
            httpSecurity.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
        }


        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
   ```

   }

I also read in some tutorial they also create a Bean of DaoAuthenticationProvider. something like below
Is is really required?

```
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder);
    return authProvider;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code can be replaced by loading the bean from the applicationContext of Spring which will not throw this issue in SonarQube.

```
 @Autowired
 private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

 @Autowired
 private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
```

You can inject an applicationContext and load the classes and use the method directly in the places where you can use the jwtRequestFilter and jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint.

```
@Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
 public class SecurityConfig {
 
 
 @Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    
    
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint getAuthEntryPoint() {
        return applicationContext.getBean(JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);
    }
    
    
    private JwtRequestFilter getRequestFilter() {
        return applicationContext.getBean(JwtRequestFilter);
    }
 
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
       httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
             .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("/user/updatePassword").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
             .and()                        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(getAuthEntryPoint()).and().sessionManagement()
             .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);


       if (sslEnable) {
         httpSecurity.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
       }
 
      httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(getRequestFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
      ..
      ..
     }
 }
```